# Providing negative images in Vertex AI Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've trained a quite accurate model in Vertex AI with a single label and ~5000 images with ~10,000 objects labeled.
My input data contains images without any objects, and some of them are very different than the images used for training. The trained model has never seen them (as they have no labels), and often wrongly detects an object in them.

What I need is a way to add a negative examples to the model training (images that don't contain any object in them). I tried to add unlabeled images to the dataset, but it looks like the training process ignores those.

Comment: What *exactly* is your *programming* issue and *question* here?

Comment: This is not a programming issue per-se, but a question regarding Vertex AI usage. My question is "how to include images which don't contain labeled objects in Vertex AI object detection training?"

Comment: If it is not a *programming* issue, I am afraid it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Vertex AI... I tried labeling false positives as a new category "incorrect", but this reduced accuracy significantly.

I think the only solution is to provide images of true positives that contain objects that are similar to false positives in the background. This is not always possible and, as far as I can see, a limitation of Vertex AI.